# NodeJs server freezes, ctrl+c unfreezes it occasionally

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I have a node.js server that replies to ajax request, I click on the webpage and an ajax call is sent and it runs the function but occasionally the server freezes, sometimes doing `ctrl+c` unfreezes it and it continues processing the request, sometimes it doesn't and I have to restart it.

Code:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("Header");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
  console.log("Header sent!")

});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {

    r.getSubreddit('HighRes').getRandomSubmission().then(function(post){

        if(post.url.includes(".jpg")){
            currentUrl = post.url;
            console.log(currentUrl);
            res.send(currentUrl);
            res.end();

        } else{

            console.log("Wrong format");
        }

        });
    console.log("Got request");
    //res.end();


})

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port

   console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some issue with your `/` route. In case, url contains `jpg`, you are returning response, but, in other case, you aren't returning anything. Hence your request is in waiting state.

Try the following code.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    r.getSubreddit('HighRes').getRandomSubmission().then(function(post){
        if(post.url.includes(".jpg")){
            currentUrl = post.url;
            console.log(currentUrl);
            res.send(currentUrl);
        } else{
            console.log("Wrong format");
            res.send('Wrong format');   //you should return something here too
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much it actually fixed!